# how to control the restrict some user to search part of information in open ldap?

Tags: configuration, ldap, openldap

I am new to OpenLDAP. I would like to know the method to restrict some user from searching part of the LDAP database.

For example, I have `ldap root dn <dc=abc,dc=com>`

There are other groups like below:

```
ou=department1,dc=abc,dc=com
ou=department2,dc=abc,dc=com
ou=people,dc=abc,dc=com
cn=userA,ou=people,dc=abc,dc=com
cn=userB,ou=people,dc=abc,dc=com
```

I would like to allow userA to only able to search data from dn:

```
ou=department1,dc=abc,dc=com
```

But restrict it from searching from dn: `ou=department2,dc=abc,dc=com`

How could I implement that?

Comment: This can be done via the 'access' command in slapd.conf, which you need to look up. Too broad to answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set permissions and blocks in the slapd.conf file --- the base install has a few samples

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure ACLs in the slapd.conf file. Here are two examples ACLs that you could use for your case. But remember to add whatever other permissions for other users to "ou=department1,dc=abc,dc=com" and "ou=department2,dc=abc,dc=com".

```
access to dn="ou=department1,dc=abc,dc=com"
      by dn="cn=userA,ou=people,dc=abc,dc=com" read
      by * none

access to dn="ou=department2,dc=abc,dc=com"
      by dn="cn=userA,ou=people,dc=abc,dc=com" none
      by * none
```

For more information, read the documentation about OpenLdap access control: http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html